# Laravel: Custom validation messages in Custom Form Requests

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I am trying to keep my controller clean and move the custom request validation in to a separate class as:

```
public function register(RegisterUserRequest $request)
```

and in there define all the usual functions, such as

```
public function rules(),
public function messages(), and
public function authorize()
```

However, the frontend is expecting the following data to display:
   `title` (title related to the validation error message), `description` (which is the the actual validation error message), and  `status` (=red, yellow etc)

How can I actually customise the response of the request?

Something like this, does not seem to be working:

```
protected function  failedValidation(\Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator $validator)
        {
            $response = new Response(['data' => [],
                'meta' => [
                    'title' => 'Email Invalid'
                    'description' => '(The error message as being returned right now)',
                    'status' => 'red'
                ]);

            throw new ValidationException($validator, $response);

    }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by making request in laravel as the following :

php artisan make:request FailedValidationRequest

this command will create class called FailedValidationRequest in

App\Http\Request directory and you cab write your rules inside this class as the following:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class FailedValidationRequest extends FormRequest
{
/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
       'title' => 'required'
       'description' => 'required',
       'status' => 'required|numeric'
    ];
}
```

}

and if you  want to customize the error message you can download the language you want from this link using composer:
https://packagist.org/packages/caouecs/laravel-lang

and write the language you want by copying the languge folwder to the lang directory in your resource folder.

```
'custom' => [
    'title' => [
        'required' => 'your custom message goes here',
    ],
 'decription' => [
        'required' => 'your custom message goes here',
    ],
   ],
```

Comment: Thanks, Ali. This is not what I was exactly meaning.

I mean that if ie the 'title' field is empty, I want to return to the frontend:

[
'title' => 'Title empty'
                    'description' => 'The title field is empty)',
                    'status' => 'red'
]

Comment: in this directory resources/lang/en/validation.php

Comment: you can see this

Comment: 'custom'               => [
        'title' => [
        'required' => 'Title empty 'description',
    ],
    ],
you can add your custom message here

Comment: Many thanks, I am going to give this a try and come back to you

Comment: Hi @ali, could you please update your answer so to see the formatted code?

Comment: Thanks @ali, it's not what I exactly look for